# How to convert result in table format to a list in python ?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, data-structures, scipy

I am using python to obtain a certain output in a table format. The table has x rows and y columns. What should I do to print all the data from a specific row or specific column in a python list? (say I want to print all the data in the 3rd column in a list )

Comment: Could you please show us a sample of this table?

Comment: `list(df.iloc[:,2])` or `df.iloc[:,3].tolist()` this will transform the data in the third column to a list. NOTE `python starts counting from 0. thus the third column is index 2

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso Its just a standard table that was created with 3 columns and 5 rows.

Comment: Is it a pandas dataframe? Or a text csv? Or...?  How to access the data is dependent on how it is stored, so knowing the data type being used to store the data is very helpful to answer your question.

Comment: There isn't such a thing as a `standard table` in Python.  Why the `scipy` tag?  Not `numpy` or `pandas`?

Comment: Well, actually I am using a python program to run the azure CLI. I get the value in the table format. So, I want to parse through the values and add all details of a specific column in  a python list.

Comment: Is it csv text file?